# Transformation from GK/ETRS89 to UTM/ETRS89 in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a dataset with about 10.000 points and their coordinates in Epsg 31467, EPSG 25832 and something called Lagestatus 320 (GK and ETRS89,  tú i don‘t know correct proj4 definition). I use NTv2 and a local Grid file to transform to 25832 and this works fine!

But the way back to 31467 or Lagestatus 320 does not work. All coordinates are inf. I have no idea, what is wrong!

Do I need a different Grid file?

Comment: NTv2 files normally convert between 2 geographic CRS, so the file likely converts between DHDN (used in 31467) and ETRS89. NTv2 files can be used in both directions. Converting between 25832 and Lagestatus 320 or to 4258 (ETRS89) should work as they're all ETRS89-based.

Comment: Thank you. I take the original coordinates in 25832 and transform to 31467 using reprojct vector layer. But wenn I do this I get two errors.

Comment: :"Export in Vektordatei schlug fehl. Fehler: Transformation eines Punkts schlug beim Zeichnen eines Objekts ...fehl. Schreiben beendet (Ausnahme Vorwärtstransformation von (~numbers~) PROJ.4: .... Fehler: latitude or longitude exceeded limits. The first german part  is „ Transformation of a point failed after drawing of an object“

Comment: If you are working with Windows, you can try GeoTKF (http://gis.makobo.de/geotkf/) to find fault isolation. There you can also integrate your NTv2.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the reason why it does not work. The x value in UTM ist about **32**550650 and this seems to be the problem. I reduced the value to 550650 and it works and the results are very good.

Nerv

Comment: Try `EPSG:5652`. It has the leading 32 for the UTM zone built-in.